# Wait for set amount of if statements to continue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm sure a case would be effective here and possibly go through the case each time. Essentially I want to go through 5 commands before breaking out (Unless I do another command which forces it to break out).

It uses node.js and socket.io to use socket/io.emits on the index.html page.

***Here is what I have so far in my node file:***

```
//Commands
client.addListener('chat', function (channel, user, message) {
    console.log(user.username + ': ' + message);
    var msg = message;
    var Answerstate = 0;

    if (msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("!ff") == 0) {
        var parts = msg.split(" ");
        if(parts.length > 1) {
            parts.shift();
            var player = parts.join(" ");
            client.say(channel, player + " wants to play Family Fortunes!");
        }
        if (Answerstate < 5) {
            if (msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("!answer") == 0) { 
                var parts = msg.split(" ");
                if(parts.length > 1) {
                    Answerstate++; //Increase State
                    parts.shift();
                    var answer = parts.join(" ");
                    io.emit('answer',{player, answer}); 
                    console.log('Going over to index.html | io.emit "answerState" ');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

index.html:

```
    player       = {};
    answer       = {};
    socket.on('answer', function (player, answer) {
        console.log('player');
        console.log('answer');
    });
```

I want it follow this pattern:

1. I execute !ff "NAME"
2. They type !answer "ANSWER"
3. The state of the answer stays as it was left before hand, so someone else can pick it up at a later time. This is stored in the variable answerState but changed in the index.html page as I have that open the whole time.
4. In index.html I want it so every time someone types !answer %ANSWER% it queries if it's correct, if it is. Then carry on. If not, exit out.

Struggling to tackle this, looking at possibly a function? But even then it'l execute the function really quickly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

I may have misunderstood. If you want the former to be run once and picked up at a later time your variable **Answerstate** needs to be global, or else every time your code is run it will be redefined and set to 0.

You can define your function and just make a call to it if **Answerstate < 5**.

```
//Commands
//Define answerState as a global
var answerState = 0;
//Define your original function as a variable to insert as an argument to 
//client.addListener() and pass the answerState argument to it
var answerQuestion = function (channel, user, message, answerState) {

    console.log(user.username + ': ' + message);
    var msg = message;

    if (msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("!ff") == 0) {
        var parts = msg.split(" ");
        if(parts.length > 1) {
            parts.shift();
            var player = parts.join(" ");
            client.say(channel, player + " wants to play Family Fortunes!");
        }
        if (answerState < 5) {
           if (msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("!answer") == 0) { 
                var parts = msg.split(" ");
                if(parts.length > 1) {
                    parts.shift();
                    var answer = parts.join(" ");
                    io.emit('answer',{player, answer}); 
                    console.log('Going over to index.html | io.emit "answerState" ');
                    //if answer is correct break out of function
                    if (answer === correct) {
                        answerState = 0;
                        return;
                    } 
                    //call the function recursively until answerState = 5
                    else {
                        answerQuestion(channel, user, message, answerState++);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//add your listener and insert answerQuestion as the argument with answerState
client.addListener('chat', answerQuestion(channel, user, message, answerState));
```

Comment: The reason I've avoided a while loop is because I've heard it can really mess with the browser and cause crashes. I assume I've read wrong?

Comment: See my edit, if you want to rerun the code at a later time, instead of all at once and keep making calls to it. You may want to declare your variable Answerstate as global variable outside of the function. That way you can run through that function multiple times without resetting it back to 0. You could avoid a while or for loop completely.

Comment: I haven't heard of while loops being dangerous in browsers though, I'm not sure.

Comment: I edited the code to convey the changes that might need to take place to get your code working properly.

Comment: Hey David, So, I ended up tackling this differently. It's now two seperate commands, one called !ff which initliases the gamestatus variable I made. If `GameStatus = 1` then `player` can do !answer which sends an `io.emit` to the html page. I will tick your answer though as it did indeed work.